# Rsync copies too many directories being executed via bash script

Tags: bash, rsync

Originally I would like to sync directory (with all files and subdirectories) given in parameter in bash script.

I found this post: [How can I recursively copy a directory into another and replace only the files that have not changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601247/how-can-i-recursively-copy-a-directory-into-another-and-replace-only-the-files-t) which explains how to use rsync in similar case.

My bash script is quite simple and listed below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Type the project to be deployed: \c "
read project
echo -e "* Deploying: $project *"    
echo -e "Sync: /var/repo/released/$project"
echo -e "      /var/www/released/$project"

rsync -pr /var/repo/released/$project /var/www/released/$project
```

As a result it copies everything within /released (there are many directories in there, let's say -projects-).

I would like to copy (sync) only project given in parameter.

Could you please advice how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the script without an argument (which most likely is what you're doing since you interactively read the project name into the variable `$project`), the positional parameter `$1` remains empty. Therefore the script will `rsync` the entire content of `/var/repo/released/`.

You need to replace `$1` with `$project` in your script. Also, I'd recommend to put double quotes around the paths to avoid problems due to spaces in a directory name.

```
rsync -pr "/var/repo/released/$project" "/var/www/released/$project"
```

Comment: that was the reason, quotes + $project instead of $1